# SOAPMessage GZIP implementation

Tags: java, soap, gzip, message

I want to implement GZIP for SOAPMessage.
Below is normal SOAP client call code -

```
    // Create a new SOAP message from the factory and set the SOAPAction header.

    MessageFactoryImpl factory = new MessageFactoryImpl();
    SOAPMessage soapMsg = factory.createMessage();

    // Set the SOAP envelope contents to our ebXML DOM.

    SOAPPart part = soapMsg.getSOAPPart();
    part.setContent(new DOMSource(docSoapReq));

    // Create a SOAPConnection to send the SOAP request on.

    SOAPConnectionFactory conFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection con = conFactory.createConnection();

    // Point to the service we want to call, and then call it.  
    // Store the response in  the "reply" object.

    URLEndpoint endPoint = new URLEndpoint(serviceURL);


    SOAPMessage reply = con.call(soapMsg, endPoint);
    con.close();

    return (reply);
```

How i can implement GZIP in SOAPMessage in above mentioned code.
I did google for this but haven't found any useful things.

Please advise how can i implement it SOAPMessage.

Comment: Above given example is of SOAP message with SAAJ

Answer (score 2):

```
MimeHeaders headers = soapMsg.getMimeHeaders();
heders.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
```

giving unreadable response in jdk 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following to set the accept-encoding header:

```
MimeHeaders headers = soapMsg.getMimeHeaders();
heders.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
```